# workbox with webpack 5 generates no precache Manifest

Tags: webpack, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I am currently trying to set up the new webpack 5.0.0-alpha2 with the workbox InjectManifest Plugin.

As far as i know this should generate a precacheManifest and inject this into my serviceWorker and replace the `workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || []);`.

But for me, no precacheManifest is getting generated and this line persists.

This is my Workbox Webpack plugin configuration:

```
        new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
            swSrc: './src/Login/js/sw/sw.js',
            swDest: 'sw/sw.js'
          }),
```

So nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using  "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.0" and it works fine.

**In Webpack**

```
const { InjectManifest } = require("workbox-webpack-plugin");
```

**In Webpack Plugin Section**

```
new InjectManifest({
      swSrc: "./service-worker.js",
      swDest: `${BUILD_Folder}/service-worker.js`,
      exclude: [/test.*/]
    })
```

in your Dest folder can you check if importScripts script is there with manifest and workbox-cdn workbox-sw.js file